# PHP: Logging or tracking when an inherited class calls a parent function

Tags: php, class, inheritance, yii

I'm in the process of trying to track outdated or unused functions inside an object class.  One idea I had was to create a new class that inherits that original class, and then "track" when that parent's functions are called.  When detected, I will migrate the parent's function into the child until eventually only the necessary/needed functions exist.

Is there code that does this automatically within PHP?  Here is in example.

```
class OldUser {
    function getFullName() {
        return "{$this->firstName} {$this->lastName}";
    }
}

class User extends OldUser {

}

-----

$user = new User;
echo $user->getFulLName();
```

---

Then in a log somewhere I note:
"{timestamp} function getFullName() called"

Obviously I could add these logs manually, but if there is an existing way for PHP to do it I'd love to default to that methodology.

Alternatively, if there is a better way to do this I am open to suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: There are IDEs out there that let you see call hierarchy of functions. I think Sublime Text 3 at least had a plugin. Or searching a project folder for method names. Finding unused methods that way may be tedious but doable. As for what you mean by outdated I am not sure where you are going with that nor how this class inheritance is going to be helping. Also, logging a lot (read/writes) will kill an apps performance so be careful with that.

Comment: The idea is that code has changed so much (even before I began work on it) that functions are deprecated and no longer in use.  We're looking for a way to slowly weed out those functions so that we can clean up the code, removing them safelty.

Comment: I can tell you from experience this process is manual and time consuming. You can spend a lot of time to instrumenting your code or put in a code analysis tools but you would be way further ahead to just go class by class and find and fix what you need to. Even in the code bases I manage that was quicker over the course of a couple releases. Biggest help was a good testing framework.

Answer (score 2):

If your code is too magic for static code analysis tools, you should probably write some integration/functional tests for your app and take a look at code coverage - non-covered methods may be a dead code (or you need more tests). After this you will not only have cleaner code, but also useful test, so two birds with one stone. :)

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to achieve this without having to manually add the calls is to use a class that **doesn't** inherit the class you want to track/log:

Something around these lines should do it:

```
class User{
    private $old_user;

    // use the same signature of your class constuctor here
    public function __construct($arg1, $arg2, ...)
    {
        $this->old_user = new OldUser($arg1, $arg2, ...);
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        log(sprintf("%s: function %S() called", date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), $name));
        call_user_func_array([$this->old_user,$name], $arguments);
    }
}
```

Comment: A version of this worked exactly how I was hoping it would.  Thank you!

Comment: Great, I'm glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do from there is implement all of the public methods of `OldUser` and have those calls trigger the logging and then call the parent function. eg:

```
class User extends OldUser {
    protected function log($method, $backtrace) {
        // ...
    }
    public function getFullName() {
        $this->log(__METHOD__, debug_backtrace());
        return parent::getFullName();
    }
}
```

[`debug_backtrace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) will allow you to track down *where* in the code that the function was called.

Comment: Hmm. That's similar to what I'm trying to do.  The idea is that I'd have something like

public function getFullName() {
        self::log(__FUNCTION__  . " accessed in UserOld");
        return "{$this->firstName} {$this->lastName}";
}

Then, after seeing that in the log, copy getFullName()  into User, thus preventing it from being called anymore.

If this could be accomplished automatically with existing PHP functionality I'd rather do that then a log line into 120+ functions.